# IMapper mock returning null

Tags: unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I have an application in .net core in which I am using automapper in one of my service. Now the issue is I am writing test method and mocking automapper but it is returning null.
Here is the service method:

```
var users = _mapper.Map<IList<User>>(data);
```

and here is mocking using Moq:

```
var userLogsList = new List<User>() { new User() {Id = "1234", Name= "Dummy User"}};
var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<List<UserEntity>, IList<User>>(It.IsAny<List<UserEntity>>()))
.Returns(userLogsList);
```

Now this mock returining null everytime. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: In your moq what method on IMapper are you actually mocking ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can also consider using an actual `IMapper` instance configured specifically for the test.

```
// Arrange

//Configure mapping just for this test
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap<User, UserEntity>();
    cfg.CreateMap<UserEntity, User>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper(); // IMapper to be injected into subject under test

//...
```

If a dependency can be used without much knock on effect and minimal configuration then there is not always a reason to have to use a mock.

In this case the configuration is much simpler than creating a mock and you get the full functionality of the dependency with no additional work.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've set up Moq to intercept calls to the `IMapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source)` overload, but your code under test calls the `IMapper.Map<TDestination>(object source)` overload.

You should mock the latter:

```
var userLogsList = new List<User>() { new User() {Id = "1234", Name= "Dummy User"}};
var mapperMock = new Mock<IMapper>();
mapperMock.Setup(m => m.Map<IList<User>>(It.IsAny<object>()))
          .Returns(userLogsList);
```

I'm assuming the signatures for `IMapper` as described [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/blob/master/src/AutoMapper/IMapper.cs).

Comment: Completely blanked that I have to override specific overloads with Mock. Good spot!

Answer (score 1):

The reason you have to invoke automapper config is because, the UNIT Test cases instance runs outside of main application start up files/configs. Hence the auto mapper configuration has to be called and setup before any unit tests start to run. Ideally you place it in TestInitialize methods.